# Importing list_iterator

Tags: python

How do you import `list_iterator` instead of doing `type(iter([]))`?

I'm creating a

```
def assertIteratorEqual(self, iter_1, iter_2, msg=None, iter_type=None):
```

function, in parallel to the existing

```
def assertSequenceEqual(self, seq_1, seq_2, msg=None, seq_type=None):
```

function.

Why would types still matter in this case? The iterator could be in a class, and there's a reason to test for that.

Why can't I just convert iterators to lists and test them? Some iterated results share resources, copying them upon each iteration would not be very efficient, so converting them to a list is not always possible.

Now, the actual reason I want a list iterator type is to have a convenient type to test for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65446/discussion-on-question-by-simonzack-importing-list-iterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not exposed, but this works in cpython3.4:

```
>>> from _collections_abc import list_iterator
>>> list_iterator is type(iter([]))
True
```

generally a bad idea, though.

Comment: The reference in `_collections_abc` is private and only used to register with the `collections.abc.Iterable` ABC. The OP should just use *that* instead.

Comment: of course he should, but obviously does not want to.

Comment: And the solution for Python 3 is?

Comment: So? Just because the OP is stubborn doesn't mean we cannot tell them what the *right* approach is. These answers are not just here for the OP either. And `list_iterator = type(iter([]))` is just as valid as accessing a module that is an implementation detail (hint, never rely on modules starting with `_` to remain available between versions).

Comment: that's why I specified the exact version it works with, and stated that's a bad idea.